# Is there any collection of 'magic' headers of filetypes which is compatible with Unix `file` Command?

Tags: linux, file, unix, header, magic-numbers

I am trying to find a magic header collection of file types which can be feeded to file command using `file -m` but no avail.

Distro pre included file heaers are not too many to detect all the file types on the internet..

Has anyone come up with any collection , which is more than default list?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this programming related ?

Comment: @nos: yes.  Understanding file formats helps people understand how to program applications that use them.

Comment: Yes , i am using libmagic , *python magic module* . For clarification i mention about file command as it is well known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FILE SIGNATURES TABLE](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) from **Gary Kessler** is usually a good reference.

According to him, [this page](http://www.garykessler.net/library/magic.html) provides a copy of a magic file recovered from a *Red Hat Linux* system.

Comment: Thanks , after comparing my magic file list to the above , i am quite impressed. the magic file presented there have 204K , mine is 1.03 MB :) so Its good :)